# Authorize.net accept-sdk onencryptionfinished() is not getting called.

Tags: android, authorize.net

Hi I am trying to get token from authorize.net using accept sdk.

when I enter the wrong credit card number onEncryptionFailed is getting called but when everything is right, onEncryptionFinished is not getting called.

I took the code from https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/accept-sample-android

It is given for androidstudio. But I am doing it in eclipse. I took jars from library and installed them in maven.

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
/*
   build an Accept SDK Api client to make API calls.
   parameters:
     1) Context - current context
     2) AcceptSDKApiClient.Environment - Authorize.net ENVIRONMENT
*/

try {
  apiClient = new AcceptSDKApiClient.Builder(this,
      AcceptSDKApiClient.Environment.SANDBOX).connectionTimeout(
      4000) // optional connection time out in milliseconds
      .build();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading",
        "Progress", true);

    try {
      EncryptTransactionObject transactionObject = prepareTransactionObject();

      /*
        Make a call to get Token API
        parameters:
          1) EncryptTransactionObject - The transactionObject for the current transaction
          2) callback - callback of transaction
       */
      apiClient.getTokenWithRequest(transactionObject, this);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      // Handle exception transactionObject or callback is null.
      Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if (progressDialog.isShowing()) progressDialog.dismiss();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you get the solution ?? And how you are managing the next step?

Comment: @curiousMind, sorry for being super late. I fixed the problem. The problem is with the jars . I took aar files from the library and added as source for my project.